# how can i make code which is that input is a specific date and output is the day of the week?

Tags: python, class, datetime, try-except

i want to use **Class** and **try~except** function to make codes.
input is that i put **integer (ex: 20160101)** then it converts to **datetime**.
And final output is **the day of the week.**

I think i can convert integer to date like this:

```
>>>import datetime 
>>>d = "20160101" 
>>>d_datetime = datetime.datetime.strptime(d, '%Y%m%d')
```

but i don't know how to make code example using class,please help me to make codes...

Comment: You need to make an attempt first, or else you won't be able to get much help.  We can help you fix problems, but not write code for you.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand exactly what you are looking for,
may be you want something like this

```
import datetime

class Day:
    def __init__(self, date_str):
        self._date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y%m%d')

    def dayOfWeek(self):
        return self._date.weekday()


d = Day("20011222")
print (d.dayOfWeek())
```